# ASP.Net Timer Keeping Original Time After Changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a timer in my ASP.NET code using C# that I am immediately changing it's Interval for, however it never actually sticks when running on the server.  The timer continues to fire every 10 seconds.  I want it to fire after the first 10 seconds, execute my code `LoadReport()`, but then wait 5 minutes to fire every other time.  The strange thing is debugging on my local machine it behaves exactly as expected, just not on the server where it will be running.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**  This appears to be a ViewState problem, however I don't know how to fix it.  Not only is the timer not keeping it's interval, but when I make charts on the page Visible they are not becoming visible.  It's as if on the server any dynamic code changes to the view of the page are being ignored, but not in development.  I've tried restarting the server but that did not fix the problem.

```
<asp:Timer ID="TimerRefreshDashboards" runat="server" Interval="10000" 
        ontick="TimerRefreshDashboards_Tick" Enabled="False">

protected void TimerRefreshDashboards_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimerRefreshDashboards.Interval = 300000;

    LoadReport();
}
```

Comment: If you want to adjust the interval in code, then you need to only ever set it in code. Similar to if you had markup `<asp:TextBox Text="SomeValue" Id="txtBox">` then setting txtBox.Text = "someOthervalue" in the code behind would not change text because it is statically set in the mark-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a single server environment. It did have other changes in place and the dates on the .dlls were the most recent. I ended up manually copying files back to the server from months ago and then redeploying from Visual Studio which now seems to have worked. I didn't even have to change anything. My original code from above now works.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, the `<asp:Timer />` control still has to be turned into some combination of HTML, javascript and CSS for your browser to understand it. (Not even Internet Explorer understands raw .NET webforms tags, so you can't expect chrome, FF, etc. to do so)

When you view the HTML source code of your page in your browser, and look at where that webforms tags would be, what you will see instead is something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(10000, RunPostBackCode(args);
</script>
```

The specifics of that tag will get generated by .NET, but suffice it to say, the `10000` argument is taken from your `Interval` property. Now, let's say that you that property in C#. If you **reload the page** you will see:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(300000, RunPostBackCode(args);
</script>
```

But let's say that you don't reload the page. Let's say that you have it in an ajax panel or update panel, or whatever. If you don't reload the page, AKA don't refresh the plain text that is the HTML, then the original `10000` will still be there.

You should not think about postbacks as a magical tool. They operate within the same restrictions as a plain old static .htm file, and changing properties on the server does not necessarily mean they change on the browser the minute you modify them (although there are tricks to do this). A postback works exactly as it sounds, the page must go back to the server and reload itself with new values changing the way .NET translates your .NET tags into HTML for the proper changes to be displayed. The `<asp:Timer />` is a particularly weird instance of this because it is meant often to cirumvent postback behavior.

Comment: The weird thing I can't get around is why does it work when running from my development machine?  It is in an ajax panel `asp:UpdatePanel` if that helps.  I've even tried in page_load to change the value but running from the server it stays at whatever is in the asp:Timer tag in this case 10000 regardless of what I put in page_load.

Comment: It's strange that changing things on page_load do not propogate to the html. Things to check: are you deploying your bin/.dll's to the server? The backend code runs from there, even though the tags are in the .aspx files. Are you running IIS with any strange settings? I've never heard of .aspx pages rendering properly, while not handling postbacks properly. Are you running in a webfarm, with multiple webservers? If one changes the value but you get another server's form it will have the original value.

Comment: It is a single server environment.  It did have other changes in place and the dates on the .dlls were the most recent.  I ended up manually copying files back to the server from months ago and then redeploying from Visual Studio which now seems to have worked.  I didn't even have to change anything.  My original code from above now works.  I would still like to know why what I did worked.

Comment: My guess is that you monkeyed around with some branches in your git or SVN and ended up deploying an older version, but that assumes a lot. I **think** VS compiles fresh dll's every time it does a deploy, but if not then that may also be the cause. Lastly, I agree with you that the deploy tool has been solid for publishing for web for a while now, so it's probably just a fluke. Glad you solved it.